# Creating Paypal Donate button without access to PayPal account

Tags: security, paypal

I am building a website for a not for profit. I had the treasurer of the charity create a PayPal account for the charity and they have the PayPal login information.

I am trying to follow best practices for security and for this reason I, as the programmer, should not need to have the ability to login to their PayPal account. If for no other reason than if someone screws with the account or diverts money they will not put me on the list of suspects this seems to be the best way.

What I do need to do is put a donate button on their website. Normally one would simply login to PayPal and PayPal will generate the HTML code for you. If the client were proficient I could have them do this and email me the code snippet, but such is not the case.

What is the minimum amount of information I need from the treasurer, the account number? Also what is the easiest way for them to get me the information I require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need the email associated with the Paypal account receiving the donations to [Create a Donate Button](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside).

The above link will generate the following markup for you:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="josh@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Stackoverflow">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The only line you will have to alter is the `business` input, which will be the Paypal account recipient.